# Is such a token method reasonable?

Tags: php, mysql, token

After successful login, create token, record in mysql. The created token pass further with session.

At first password protected page check if session token is the same as token in mysql.

To other password protected pages can get only through the first page (for example, called menu).

In the first password protected page create additional token, called page_token (also record in mysql?; is there better/faster way without mysql?; may be something like this:

```
(isset($_SESSION) == $_SESSION['page_token']))
```

Session token remains the same, page_token changes after each page reload.

On all other pages check if session token and page_token are the same as tokens in mysql.

Is such method would be good? May be better method exists (some link)?

Thank you

**Update**

Searched online. Understand that above method is not reasonably. Would be enough to check session loggedin.

But want to be as much sure as possible that visitor of particular password protected page is the same visitor that entered correct username and password.

So next questions

1) What do you think about this tutorial http://wblinks.com/notes/secure-session-management-tips

2) What do you think about the code? Can normal user change any of below HTTP during one session?

```
if( $_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1 or $_SESSION['time_when_form_submitted'] > date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
or
$_SESSION['_USER_LOOSE_IP'] != long2ip(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long("255.255.0.0"))
or
$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
or
$_SESSION['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
or
$_SESSION['HTTP_ACCEPT'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']
or
$_SESSION['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
 ) {
header('Refresh: 0; URL=http://www.domain.com/login.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use tokens in your login form i remember i watched a nice tutorial about that here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNU1CYryF_8

after you check if the the user and pass are correct if you don't want to check on every page load the login details you can make a session var that will store the user id or something like that so you can use that for is_loggedin() function